# How do I check if all elements in a list are the same?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

If i have this list;

```
mylist = ['n', 'n', '4', '3', 'w']
```

How do I get it to read the list, and tell me whether or not they are all the same?

I am aware that it is easy to tell they are not all the same in this example. I have much larger lists I would like it to read for me.

Would I go about this using:

```
min(...)
```

If so, how would I input each list item?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use set like this

```
len(set(mylist)) == 1
```

**Explanation**

sets store only unique items in them. So, we try and convert the list to a set. After the conversion, if the set has more than one element in it, it means that not all the elements of the list are the same.

**Note:** If the list has unhashable items (like lists, custom classes etc), the `set` method cannot be used. But we can use the first method suggested by @falsetru,

```
all(x == mylist[0] for x in mylist)
```

**Advantages:**

1. It even works with unhashable types
2. It doesn't create another temporary object in memory.
3. It short circuits after the first failure. If the first and the second elements don't match, it returns `False` immediately, whereas in the `set` approach all the elements have to be compared. So, if the list is huge, you should prefer the `all` approach.
4. It works even when the list is actually empty. If there are no elements in the iterable, `all` will return `True`. But the empty list will create an empty `set` for which the length will be 0.

Comment: Note that this only works on hashable items. Doing this on a list of lists wouldn't work for instance.

Comment: @Tyler: this is too clever. It hashes every item in a list of N items, which can be quite expensive; instead of just comparing them.

Comment: beware of edge cases e.g. `mylist = [float('nan')]`

Answer (score 14):

Using [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
all(x == mylist[0] for x in mylist)
```

Alternative:

```
mylist.count(mylist[0]) == len(mylist)
```

**NOTE** The first will stop as soon as it found there's any different item in the list, while the alternative will not.

Comment: Note this also works on the trivial case of an empty list (as opposed to erroring out).

Comment: `mylist.count`? Really? I thought that alternative was added as a joke. Any solution that exits early is better than one that always reads the whole sequence no matter what. Maybe add a guard against an empty list, or convert to an iterator in case you get a generator instead. But some solution involving `all` is definitely the proper course.